# jQuery Validation plugin: Conditional textfield validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been stumped for three days over this issue. I'm a front-end developer with very little programming background so I have little knowledge of javascript.

The issue is this: I have two text fields. If both text fields are NULL, then there would be an error validation to fill out one or the other. If one of the text fields is filled, then the other will not longer be a required field.

Here's what I have for the HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li>
     <label for="billingAcctNo">Your account number:&nbsp;*</label>
             <input type="text" name="billingAcctNo" id="billingAcctNo" class="textfield" />
       </li>
       <li>
             <label for="billingMobileNo">Or your mobile phone number:&nbsp;*</label>
     <input type="text" name="billingMobileNo" id="billingMobileNo" class="textfield" />
       </li>
```

And this is what I have for my validation:

```
$("#form").validate({
      rules: {
          billingAcctNo:    {
           required: "#serviceBilling:checked"
      },
      billingMobileNo: {
            required: "#serviceBilling:checked",
            phoneUS: true
        }
       },
    messages: {
                 billingAcctNo: "Please enter a valid account number or mobile number",
        billingMobileNo: {
            required: "Please enter a valid account number or mobile number",
            phoneUS: "Please enter a valid mobile phone number"
        }
});
```

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Change you rules config to as mentioned below.

```
rules: {
          billingAcctNo:    {
           required: true
      },
      billingMobileNo: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - this has a radio button I must click on beforehand called ##serviceBilling, which is why it is there.

I need an EITHER OR statement though - either billingAcctNo is valid or billingMobileNo is valid. If it's NULL, then both have validation. If one of them is filled up, then the other text field does not have to be filled up. 

Does this sound clear, or do I need more examples?